# Typescript interface extends same interface multiple times

Tags: typescript, template-literals, typescript-types, typescript-template-literals

I have the following situation:
I have type with the following definition:

```
type A<year extends number> = `a${year}`
```

And I want to have an interface or a type such that, it has a variable amount of `A<year>` as keys as required properties and some other properties. For example:

```
interface AStatistics<years extends number[]>
extends Record<A<year0> & A<year1> ..., number>
& {
    aCommonProp: string
}
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can achieve it with interface, but you can use [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) like this:

```
type A<year extends number> = `a${year}`;

type AStatistics<TYears extends number[]> = { [K in A<TYears[number]>]: number } & { aCommonProp: string };

const stats: AStatistics<[1990, 1991, 2002]> = {
    a1990: 1,
    a1991: 2,
    a2002: 123,
    aCommonProp: "some prop"
}
```

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggPCCBDATlCAPYEB2ATAZyhwFcBbAIwhQD4oBeKAAyQBIBvRVAXyYG4AsAChhoSLADKwJMACWBOQGMCcACoBNZCiKZs+IqUrUA2gF06jdlGMBpKLJyw1m1AWOGqKc6YBcxcp5Q3FAAZFBWSADCAPZkZNE4AAoo0WB+CigOAOZBgiJCigkKUAoyBH4wUjLySirGAIwAnI0ADAA0UE2N9R0ATC0tveYM4cJQ41BIXS1+PWMTU831fr1t8+NI-YOzvQDMa0ITkzFxCcmpfgBEBLHQYClgl8LcQA) to playground.

Comment: It even makes the properties required! Thanks for the answer <3

Comment: Yes, note you can use `{ [K in A<TYears[number]>]?: number }` (with `?`) to make the properties optional.